# Insert Cables vs Stereo - split cable

Tags: cable

I will need to test the Insert connections on my Zed 24 Allen & heath mixer as I'll be hiring it out, now to avoid any doubt

I need to know

a. whether I can actually test it safely without a proper fx proccesser? 
b. If Insert cables are the same as a stereo split cable i.e.: and can I use the one I have see link

http://www.pmtonline.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1000x1000/5e06319eda06f020e43594a9c230972d/5/7/57866-dolphin-premium-1m3ft-split-63-stereo-jack----2x-63-jack-deluxe/pmtonline-stagg-st81444-31.jpg

I have a small 8 channel fx mixer behringer ub1204fx

Can use the inputs and outputs on this mixer to test it or do they need to use a proper fx processor?

will appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you are asking. Why do you want to use a fx processor to test insert connections on a mixer? can't you just use a tone generator?

Answer (score 2):

**Q1:** I've done some research, and yes, you can use the Stagg Stereo -> 2 x Mono cable in the link. It will work as an unbalanced insert lead.

From [A&H Zed 24 Manual](http://www.allen-heath.com/media/AP6822_5+ZED14_18_24UG.pdf):
[image]

**Q2:** To test the insert connections, you just need to find out if the signal is being sent/returned through the mono jacks. You could do this by connecting the Mono jacks together; tip to tip. You could use a crocodile clip wire if you wish.